# How to capture and log any 301 redirects (.htaccess) that happen using PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, logging

I have a bunch of 301 redirects set in my .htaccess file.
What I'd like to do is keep track of how many times a redirect is used, so that I can manage them better.

Is there a way to capture and log 301 redirects matches that happen with PHP?

In other words, if the redirect is:

```
RewriteRule ^about/bozo$ /about [R=301,L]
```

Is there a way to capture the "about/bozo" every time it happens using PHP?
(even though the redirects are handled by htaccess calls, and not by PHP header redirects)

Comment: You could check what the referrer contains in this situation, but a) I am not sure whether that would contain `/about/bozo` now, or the address of the document where you originally clicked on the link pointing _to_ `/about/bozo`, and b) the referrer is well known to be highly unreliable to begin with. Other than that - no, not really possible. _Because_ you are redirecting from the .htaccess already, PHP does not get invoked for that initial request. Your web server's access log should contain entries that let you see the response was given with a 301 status code though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot log a 3xx redirect that is triggered *earlier* in the request by Apache (eg. in `.htaccess`) using PHP. The redirect is entirely invisible to PHP.

You can't use the HTTP `Referer` to determine if a redirect occurred since the browser preserves the `Referer` from the initial request (if any).

Requests that trigger a 3xx redirect should be logged in the server's access log.

The only way you could do this with PHP is if you *mark* the redirected URL in some way (perhaps with a query string) and check for this in your PHP script. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^about/bozo$ /about?redirected=true [R=301,L]
```

... but that maybe undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

MrWhite's answer is correct that you can't see those redirects in PHP. However, you don't need to use PHP to get the stats you want.

If you want stats on how often those redirects happen, you can get them from your web server's `access_log` file. Every 301 redirect should add an entry in the log file regardless of whether the redirect was triggered by .htaccess or PHP.  Such a log entry should look something like this:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Jan/2000:11:55:36 -0700] "GET /about/bozo HTTP/1.1" 301 456
```

You can use command line tools to count redirects:

```
grep '" 301 ' /var/log/apache2/access_log | wc -l
```

or

```
grep 'GET /about/bozo ' /var/log/apache2/access_log | wc -l
```

Where `grep` does the filtering of the log file and `wc -l` counts the lines.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I've created a tool in a custom CMS (PHP) that allows my client to manage custom redirects (for campaign emails and such). The tool writes redirects to the .htaccess file. I want a way to show how many times any redirect has been used, so the admin user can turn they find out they are not ever being used for a long period of time (adding these numbers to the database).  Maybe I can leverage your grep commands using a PHP Cron job.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the way I would approach a problem like this.

Comment: Alternately, you could just implement the redirects in PHP itself rather than implementing them in .htaccess

Comment: Also - a good idea.